# Django and Haystack IntegerField converts to list on return

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I'm new with haystack and so that's why explanation of the problem could be not so clear.
Have a problem with storing IntegerField in haystack.
This is main part of my index model where problem is:

```
class SomeIndex(ModelSearchIndex):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel

    company = IntegerField()

    def prepare_company(self, obj):
        return obj.company.pk
```

In SomeModel's company field is FK, so I decided to serve it as IntegerField. I've checked `on update_index(using pdb.set_trace())` that value for `company` field is saving as a correct integer digit (I see it in prepare method of SearchIndex model in `haystack/indexes.py`). But when I try to get indexed items with `company` field not empty - getting error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I've looked deeper to `haystack/backends/sorl_backend.py` `SearchBackend.search` method and really when getting results in `raw_results = self.conn.search(query_string, **kwargs)` my `company` field value is list e.g. `[1]`.

What could be the reason of this? Why `company` returned as list and not int?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: try printing the type of obj.company.pk before returning, so that you you can know the type of obj.company.pk
print(type(obj.company.pk))

Comment: type is int. I've event tried to wrap obj.company.pk in int(). But no results.

Comment: Can you add the whole exception?